# openshift django opening and writing to a text file

Tags: django-views, openshift

I have created a questionnaire with django and in my views.py have the following code as part of a function

```
 if text is not None:
    for answer in datas:
        f=open('/Users/arsenios/Desktop/data.txt', 'a')
        f.write(answer+",")
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

This works fine locally. It creates a text folder on the desktop and fills it in with the data of each person that completes it. When I run the code with openshift I get:
"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/arsenios/Desktop/data.txt'".

I have seen some people asking and mentioning "OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR" but I feel like there are steps they haven't included. I don't know what changes I should make to settings.py and views.py.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It turns out the data was getting saved in data.txt in openshift and the command I had to use was `oc rsync pod:/opt/app-root/src/data.txt /path/to/directory`. This command downloaded the data.txt file from openshift to the directory I wanted to. So in my case I had to use `oc rsync save-4-tb2dm:/opt/app-root/src/data.txt /Users/arsenios/Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

The `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` is from OpenShift 2 and is not set in OpenShift 3.

The bigger question is whether that is a temporary file or needs to be persistent across restarts of the application container. If temporary file, use a name under `/tmp` directory. If it needs to be persistent, then you need to look at mounting a persistent volume to save the data in, or look at using a separate database with its own persistent storage.

For explanation of some of the fundamentals of using OpenShift 3, suggest you look at the free eBook at:

- https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

Comment: I've been trying but haven't managed to save the data. I placed data.txt in the project folder next to manage.py and changed the code to `f=open('data.txt', 'a')`. Now I can run the code in openshift but even after I created I persistent volume nothing seems to be getting saved. What I want is for openshift to interact with my data.txt on the desktop. That way when someone gets the link and runs the code the data is saved in the file. I used gitHub to add the code to openshift. Does it make any difference if I add it directly from my desktop instead?

Comment: How are you running OpenShift?

Comment: I'm using openshift origin and used oc commands for the build through a GitHub repository.

Comment: But are you using Minishift? Are you using ``oc cluster up``? Have you installed as a single node cluster direct to a Linux host? Not a question of which OpenShift version, but how you installed it and running it.

Comment: Minishift is running but I haven'y used any commands including it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong and sorry if it's silly but I'm new to openshift and haven't really gotten the hang of it yet. All I've done is follow the Command-Line Walkthrough instructions using CLI.

Comment: I also think what I said before about linking openshift with desktop is probably not possible so what I would want in that case would be to have a data.txt file in an openshift volume and save the data there. I have the data.txt in the GitHub code and so it should be in openshift too since I've clone it and, since the code is running without a problem it seems to me like the data should be getting saved in the file but I have no way of viewing it.

Comment: Have you had a look through the book I linked yet? It talks about how to access a running container using ``oc rsh``.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem using `oc rsync`. The book didn't really help in the end although I might have just missed it but thanks for your help.